# Is there a type of parameter that can (efficiently) accept one or multiple variables depending on usecase?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters

I want to make a helper function that can take 1 or more floats depending on the context in which it's being used. Pseudo version shown here:

```
void processData(float data) {
  //stuff
}
```

where I could call the function for a single variable or an array if needs be

```
float x = ...;
processData(x);

//or

float x[3] = {..., ..., ...}
processData(x);
```

Sorry if this is poorly communicated, I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for so giving specifics is kinda hard.

I've looked into using straight arrays, feels kinda goofy and innefficient to cast to every instance where a single variable is being passed to an array.

Comment: How about writing 2 overloads, one that takes a float, and one that takes an array? The 2nd one could call the first overload on each float in the array.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Best choice depends on details and version of C++ standard you can use.

Comment: `std::array` or `std::vector`...

Comment: @JesperJuhl probably `std::initializer_list` is better in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure What are you looking for, but I think that you need a vector.
The size of the vector is changeable, and it can hold different types.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it can hold different types". A `std::vector` can only hold elements of a single type.

Comment: I meant that the vector can hold different type, like the example in the question `vector<float>`.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is one value in both cases. They are of different type though. Taking your example literally, you are looking for function overloading. Rather than c-arrays prefer `std::array`. Especially when passing it to a function, because you cannot pass a c-array to a function without letting it decay to a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void processData(float x) {
    std::cout << "float x : "  << x <<"\n";
}

template <size_t N>
void processData(const std::array<float,N>& x) {
    std::cout << "float array\n";
}

int main() {
    float x = 4.2;
    processData(x);

    std::array<float,3> y{4.2, 4.2 ,4.2};
    processData(y);    
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TE1hW5cb7)